# HTML5 video only displaying poster on mobiles

Tags: android, ios, html5-video

I'm having trouble with loading an HTML5 video on mobiles.

**The problem:**

On Android Chrome and iOS Safari only the poster is displayed and the video never loads or plays. It works as expected in Chrome emulating an iPhone 6 on a desktop, however.

**The code:**

```
<video id="home-video-mobile" width="414" height="614" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" poster="http://www.tastecreative.com/wp-content/uploads/vid_mobile_poster.jpg">
    <source src="http://www.tastecreative.com/wp-content/uploads/vid_mobile.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="http://www.tastecreative.com/wp-content/uploads/vid_mobile.wemb" type="video/webm"/>
    <source src="http://www.tastecreative.com/wp-content/uploads/vid_mobile.ogv" type="video/ogv"/>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**The JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/44gLqqt9/7/

**What I've tried:**

When I remove the `autoplay` attribute and add the `controls` attribute the video loads and plays as expected after I click the play button. This isn't an acceptable solution for me because the video must play automatically and without controls.

Is this a bug or is this the expected behaviour on mobile devices? Is there any way to force mobile browsers to respect `autoplay`?

Comment: This is expected. video/audio *never* autoplay on mobile. You have to trigger play (at least the first time) inside a touch or click event. Anywhere on the screen will do.

Comment: Does it have to be a real click or can you simulate a click event with JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah, it has to be real. I'm afraid there's no free lunch here. but it could be any touch at all. doesn't have to be on the video. e.g. if you register the event on the window, it'll start when the user touches to scroll.

Comment: OK cool, thanks for the info!